# Heatmap.2 out of range

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap

Please see my plot below. I have a problem that my names get outside the plot. Changing the pdf width and height does not help. I am using Rstudio in Linux.

```
pdf(width=12,height=10)
heatmap.2(as.matrix(data.log), scale="none", col=colorRampPalette(c("blue", "white", "red"))(1000), Colv=NA, trace="none", dendrogram ="row", breaks=seq(-5, 5, 0.01)) 
dev.off()
```

[image]

Comment: `? heatmap.2` -> set `margins` to an appropriate value.